# Is there a way to have Excel's CUBESET function take multiple Sort By arguments?

Tags: excel, mdx

I'm trying to have a CUBESET function that returns ranked products by sales for a particular timeframe. I can get the sortby argument to accept [Measures].[Product Sales] and a single date utilizing Concatenate, however it would be preferable to have [Measures].[Product Sales] and a date range. I currently have the date range in a different cell as another CUBESET. Anyone know how I can do this?

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression parameter you should be able to wrap `ORDER` around the set?

```
Order( [Geography].[Country].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Product Sales],DESC )
```

You could then nest a further order:

```
ORDER( ORDER( [Geography].[Country].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Product Sales],DESC ), [Measures].[Cost],ASC)
```